# Getting SQL Error in Qlikview while trying to fetch data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, qlikview

I am trying to perform an incremental load in QlikView using MySQL datasource the error I am getting is

[image: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds]

and script I am using is

```
ODBC CONNECT TO Mysql_datasource_test;

 BKPF_TEMP:
LOAD 
//MANDT,
  BUKRS&GJAHR&BELNR AS KEY,
  BUKRS, //Company Code
  BELNR, //DocumentNo
  GJAHR, //YEAR
  BLART, //Document Type
  BLDAT, //Document Date
  BUDAT, //Posting Date
  MONAT, //Period
  CPUDT, //Entered on (To use this for the purpose of incremental load) 
  XBLNR, //Reference
  WAERS, //Currency
  KURSF  //Exchange rate
;
SQL SELECT *
FROM testtable.bkpf;
 where BLART IN ($(vDocTypes));

// Once data Initial data is loaded store the data in a QVD File
 Store BKPF_TEMP into $(vSaveQVD)BKPF_TEMP.QVD (QVD);


//// Load BKPF_TEMP QVD to get latest date updated..

 BKPF_TEMP:
 LOAD 
  //MANDT,
 KEY,
 BUKRS, //Company Code
 BELNR, //DocumentNo
 GJAHR, //YEAR
 BLART, //Document Type
 BLDAT, //Document Date
 BUDAT, //Posting Date
 MONAT, //Period
 CPUDT, //Entered on (To use this for the purpose of incremental load) 
 XBLNR, //Reference
 WAERS, //Currency
 KURSF  //Exchange rate
 FROM $(vSaveQVD)BKPF_TEMP.QVD (QVD);

// This step is to find the last updated date
BKPF:
LOAD *
Resident BKPF_TEMP
ORDER BY CPUDT;

// Looking at the last updated date
LET vUpdateDate = Peek('CPUDT',-1,'BKPF');

//// You Drop BKPF_TEMP because ordered data is already in BKPF table
DROP TABLE BKPF_TEMP;


ODBC CONNECT TO Mysql_datasource_test;
// Incremental load
BKPF_Incremental:
LOAD 
//MANDT,
   BUKRS&GJAHR&BELNR AS KEY,
BUKRS, //Company Code
BELNR, //DocumentNo
GJAHR, //YEAR
BLART, //Document Type
BLDAT, //Document Date
BUDAT, //Posting Date
MONAT, //Period
CPUDT, //Entered on (To use this for the purpose of incremental load) 
XBLNR, //Reference
WAERS, //Currency
KURSF  //Exchange rate
   ;

SQL SELECT *
   FROM testtable.bkpf
   where BLART IN ($(vDocTypes)) AND CPUDT >= $(vUpdateDate) ;

   //Concatinate incremental load with previously loaded records by adding new    records or replacing the updated records
   Concatenate
   LOAD 
  //MANDT,
   KEY,
   BUKRS, //Company Code
   BELNR, //DocumentNo
   GJAHR, //YEAR
   BLART, //Document Type
   BLDAT, //Document Date
   BUDAT, //Posting Date
   MONAT, //Period
   CPUDT, //Entered on (To use this for the purpose of incremental load) 
   XBLNR, //Reference
   WAERS, //Currency
   KURSF  //Exchange rate
   FROM $(vSaveQVD)BKPF_TEMP.QVD (QVD)
   Where not exists(KEY);

   STORE BKPF_Incremental into $(vSaveQVD)BKPF_TEMP.QVD (QVD);

   DROP TABLE BKPF_Incremental;
```

there is a SQL error on

```
   SQL SELECT *
   FROM testtable.bkpf
   where BLART IN ($(vDocTypes)) AND CPUDT >= $(vUpdateDate) ;
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the date in quotes i.e. instead of

```
BLART IN ($(vDocTypes)) AND CPUDT >= $(vUpdateDate)
```

use

```
BLART IN ($(vDocTypes)) AND CPUDT >= '$(vUpdateDate)'
```

QlikView does a text replacement of expressions inside `$(...)`, so it will not add the quotes itself.